# SPARK_JAVA_OPTS not working under EMR

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

We have Spark 1.3 running on our EC2 cluster & under that we use SPARK_JAVA_OPTS to set environment variables like this:

export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dxyz=A"

Now we're trying to port our application to EMR (on AWS) which is running Spark 1.5, but the same script is not working.

Did anything change between Spark 1.3 & Spark 1.5 with SPARK_JAVA_OPTS? Is this EMR related issue?